Usage of the word “plush”
In what contexts do you typically use the word 'plush'?
I usually see it used in the sense of “ high-quality, expensive” to describe places like restaurants and hotels.
I'm wondering if it can be used for other things as well.

Did you look in any dictionaries?

Where do you "see it in that sense"? I never have.

Plush means 'soft to touch' and also implies comfort. It's an adjective that you'd correctly use to describe a cushion, a sofa, comfortable clothing, or a cuddly toy (some such toys are called 'plushies'). You can use it to describe a room or hotel that is decorated in a comfortable way with soft furnishings (eg "a plush hotel room").
I personally would not use 'plush' to describe a restaurant - are they using bean bags for tables? Yes, restaurants and food can be 'luxurious' but it doesn't fit with the soft furnishing aspect of the definition. Apparently, some do use it that way, however - there is a Cambridge dictionary example indicating so.
It's possible that the speakers you have heard intended to use either the word posh, which means "elegant or stylishly luxurious" and is commonly used in connection with restaurants, or lush which has a colloquial use (in British English) that means beautiful, delicious or almost anything good or pleasing. Or maybe they've consulted Cambridge.

Posh might be another source of confusion.

Cambridge Dictionary says you can describe a restaurant as 'plush'! NB Cuddly toys are often made of plush - a soft, fluffy fabric.

@KateBunting I am surprised by that. It just doesn't seem right at all, but I've updated my answer to acknowledge it.
